# Error: Type 'GearViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerviewdatasource

Error:

> Type 'GearViewController' does not conform to protocol
>   'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Based on [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerviewdatasource) there are only 2 required methods for a UIPickerViewDataSource.  Both are included in the code below.  I think the syntax is correct. (but probably not)

Class/control declaration, and init.  (lots of other code removed for clarity.  Full code available if needed, i'll edit.  Just trying to stay brief.)

```
class  GearViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var pickerGearCategory: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerGearCategory.dataSource = self
        pickerGearCategory.delegate = self

    }
```

Delegate and datasources

```
  let gearCategoryPickerData = CategoryRepository.allCategories()
    //MARK: CategoryPicker- Delegates and data sources
    //MARK: CategoryPicker - Data Sources


    //Required
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerGearCategory: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //Required
    func pickerGearCategory(pickerGearCategory: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return gearCategoryPickerData.count
    }


    func pickerGearCategory(pickerGearCategory: UIPickerView,titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return gearCategoryPickerData[row].name
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the protocol method that you've implemented is wrong, the method should be:

```
func pickerView(UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent: Int) {
//Your implementation here
}
```

You've implemented the method as,

```
func pickerGearCategory(pickerGearCategory: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
//Your implementation
}
```

Correct it and you should be good to go.

Comment: got syntax error with this and the two other answers below.  Wanted   `func pickerView(_: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return gearCategoryPickerData.count
    }`

Comment: Complied with change, but need to validate getting expected results and have to head out for real job.

Comment: Thanks, with the one change it works like a charm.  Even better, it pointed out another issue that would have been the next post!

Answer (score 0):

numberOfComponents is there, but where is pickerView?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `func pickerView(UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent: Int)`
function